# Copy Files from one folder to another folder

Tags: automationanywhere

I am reading the filename from the excel spreadsheet and iterating over the files present in a specified folder. If the file name in the folder matches with the filename in the excel sheet the message "Yes" is entered in the second column of the excel sheet otherwise "No" is entered. But when the filenames are not equal "No" is not shown in the excel spreadsheet it is left as blank. I am also trying to copy the files whose file names are matched to another folder but I am getting some error.[image: The code for checking the filenames][image: No is getting displayed if filenames are not matched][image: The files are not getting copied to another folder][image: using if file exists][image]

Answer (score 0):

First thing, it would be more efficient and simpler if you use **If file exists** command.

```
If file exists ($filepath$) Then 
      Set Cell B$Counter$ = Yes
      Copy file command
Else 
      Set Cell B$Counter$ = No
```

The error happened because you are looping on files on a folder and the counter is for the file loop not for the excel.

Comment: I am getting all the B column as "No".

Comment: Could you confirm that you are checking by the correct file path? Your excel sheet only contains the file name

Comment: Note that you are not assigning anything to the $filepath$ variable.

Comment: The file path is the same as the one which is used in, Start Loop "Each File in Folder $vFilePath$"

Comment: That's a folder path, file path should be:  folder path + filename + extension
Could you attach a screenshot of your code?

Comment: If File Exists("$vFilePath$$vFileName$") Then, is this correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197574/discussion-between-khaledmostafame-and-utkarsh).